# How to use ttf fonts on windows phone 7 apps development?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="தமிழ் எழுத்து" FontSize="60" Margin="-11,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF4D5331" FontFamily="fonts/TAU_REWN.TTF#TAU_Elango_Rewathy"/>
```

I have initialized my font family like above and I have pasted my ttf font in `/fonts` folder. This bit of code works perfectly in windows phone 8 apps development. But, not works in windows phone OS 7.1 English `TTF` fonts works well. Kindly note, This is a tamil font.

Whats wrong here ? Can anyone helps...

Windows Phone 7.5 has tamil font support. Here's the [proof](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/thirukkural/47eb0571-fc61-481b-baa6-531a320a06e2)

Update with fonts

```
TTF Font is here : https://app.box.com/s/2ce5rvzfvfkm55d27196
TTF Font Name is here : TAU_Elango_Rewathy
Tamil text is also here: தமிழ் எழுத்து
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your font file's build action is set to "Content". Right click on the font, select properties and change the build action.

See tutorial over [here](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/24/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-24-embedding-fonts/) that walks you through embedding a font.

Comment: i gave that and i have went through that tutorial also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `TTF` capitalization may solve you problem i think so.

```
FontFamily="fonts/TAU_REWN.ttf#TAU_Elango_Rewathy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your ttf file in bellow path

/Assets/Fonts/Helvetica_.ttf

```
<TextBlock Name="tbSuggestionlst1" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Helvetica_.ttf#Helvetica_ "  Text="Hello World"/>
```

And Yes you have give your font name like below

```
 <TextBlock Name="tbSuggestionlst1" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Helvetica.ttf#Helvetica Bold "  Text="Hello World"/>
```

If my ttf name is **Helvetica** but font name is **Helvetica Bold** so you have to write your font name after **#** like Helvetica.ttf#Helvetica Bold "

**Edit:** i tryed in windows phone 8 with below code and it will work fine

```
<TextBlock Name="tbHdrAboutsUs" Text="தமிழ் எழுத்து"  FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/TAU_REWN.TTF#TAU_Elango_Rewathy" ></TextBlock>
```

[image]

In windows phone 7 it will not work beacuse windows phone 7 does not supported tamil fonts
Hope it will help you.

[Tamil Language support](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2283739-tamil-language-support)

It will work for me

Comment: are you sure ? have you tried this for tamil font ? i am currently developing an app for windows phone 7 ? here, no assets folder, so have to create new one ?

Comment: @user2745355:yes i am sure for my code.and Not tried with tamil font bcos dont have tamil font

Comment: @user2745355:but concern is not tamil font concern is how to bind ttf file

Comment: no if your are in windows phone 7 than no need to create Asset folder

Comment: you use windows phone 7 Than just like FontFamily="/Fonts/EARTH.TTF#EARTH"

Comment: no brother. i have tried like this. i know this method already. but failed. let me attach tamil ttf font in the question

Comment: Okey wait gor 10 minit

Comment: try this in Windows Phone OS 7.1

Comment: see my edited answerand still any query than feel free to ask me

Comment: in my question itself, you can find i know its works well in wp8 and also works well for english ttf in wp7. my query is about tamil font in wp7.

Comment: @user2745355: Boss windows phone 7 is not supported tamil font so you can not bind tamil font

Comment: yep. we cant do anything else then

Comment: tell me your full requirement so i can help you .... what you want?but you can't use indian font in windows phone 7...

Comment: most welcome and you can upgrade your project in windows phone 8

Comment: nope. Windows Phone 7 is compatible with tamil fonts. here's the [proof](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/thirukkural/47eb0571-fc61-481b-baa6-531a320a06e2)